# How to read CSS syntax on MDN

Tags: css, syntax, css-selectors

```
selectors-list ::=
    selector[:pseudo-class] [::pseudo-element]
    [, selectors-list]

properties-list ::= 
    [property : value] [; properties-list]
```

I'm trying to get familiar with CSS and I'd be happy to understand the rules of reading these (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference).

Comment: MDN seems to use an extended BNF notation to describe language syntax. You can find basic info about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form).

Comment: I have not seen this illustration of CSS syntax before. It appears to be exceedingly poorly written. Even if @Domino is right in that this is a variation of BNF, I can already spot a number of flaws in the selectors-list definition. I would suggest you ignore this illustration, because the selector syntax is richer than what it suggests. Check out MDN's [CSS primer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) instead - it's much more comprehensive yet doesn't rely on notation that would be arcane to a newcomer.

Comment: Oh, and https://flukeout.github.io/ has a pretty good interactive lesson if you want to learn the basics of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This MDN page seems to use a pseudo-BNF notation to describe CSS syntax. The notation used is very confusing because `[]` `::` `:` `;` and `,` all mean something in CSS, yet they used `[]` to represent optional parts and `::=` for grammar rule definition.

I can give you a rough English translation of what they meant:

```
style-rule ::=
    selectors-list {
      properties-list
    }
```

A style-rule is made of a selectors-list followed by `{` followed by a properties-list followed by `}`.

```
selectors-list ::=
    selector[:pseudo-class] [::pseudo-element]
    [, selectors-list]
```

A selectors-list is made of a selector, optionally followed by `:` and a pseudo-class, optionally followed by `::` and a pseudo-element, optionally followed by `,` and another selectors-list.

This definition is not only incorrect (you may use multiple pseudo-class in a row), but has a confusing name. If a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element are something separate from the selector, why would you call a list of all three a selectors-list?

Leaving that aside...

```
properties-list ::= 
    [property : value] [; properties-list]
```

A properties-list can be completely empty, or may contain a property followed by `:` followed by a value, optionally followed by `;` and another properties-list.

And then, they don't even use their pseudo-BNF to define what is a selector, a pseudo-class, a pseudo-element, a property or a value. This whole notation is way more confusing than helpful. This MDN page should probably get rewritten.

Comment: I might have been a little too informal/opinionated in that answer.

Comment: Nah, you're good. TBH, I think these were made up by whoever happened to be editing that page at the time. The CSS specs already have grammars to refer to - there's no need to try and come up with one's own representation. I find MDN to be unreliable at times for this reason. Pages are either really good or really bad, and it all depends on who's editing them.

Comment: Broader topics and tutorials are simply not updated very often because the more active editors focus on documenting new features. That tends to be a problem everywhere :)